# How old is SpongeBob?

Tags: character, spongebob-squarepants

How old is SpongeBob? I don't mean how old is the series, I mean what is SpongeBob's age if he were a real person. I ask because his age seems to be ambiguous in the show.

- He has a full-time job
- He has his own house
- He is always referred to as a kid (especially in the movie)
- He acts childish and immature
- In one episode, he was pretending to be an adult/grown-up

Comment: Great question. He's old enough to drive, but I don't know what the law about that is underwater.

Comment: @CrowTRobot you're right about not knowing the rules of underwater. If he is 13 as Walt said, then Mr Crabs is possibly violating child labor laws :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, SpongeBob [has a date of birth](http://spongebob.wikia.com/wiki/SpongeBob_SquarePants_%28character%29): July 14, 1986. If we assume that the series takes place in our times, that would make him **28**.

However, Bart and Lisa Simpson have been 8 and 10 for more than 20 years now. So if we assume that his age is *constant* in the show (which premiered in July 17, 1999), that would make him **13**.

Is that data useful in this cartoon? Not really. We don't really know what rules fictional underwater realms play by, and to further confuse matters, I'm not even sure how *relatively* old SpongeBob is because, according to Wiki, [the lifespan of a sea sponge varies greatly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponge):

> Sponges in temperate regions live for at most a few years, but some tropical species and perhaps some deep-ocean ones may live for 200 years or more.

However, it appears that the show's creator has kept SpongeBob's age vague [on purpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpongeBob_SquarePants_%28character%29#Creation_and_design):

> Although SpongeBob's driver's license says his birthdate is July 14, 1986, Hillenburg joked that he is fifty in "sponge years". He explained that **SpongeBob actually has no specific age**, but that he is old enough to be on his own and still be going to boating school.

Comment: +1 for the birth date, but great answer all around though. It sounds like he is both 28 (job, house) and 13 (childish nature) at the same time.

Comment: Hey, the Simpson kids also say and do things that are way beyond their years sometimes. So maybe you're right and it's some sort of compromise. :)

Comment: [SpongeBob is probably a Stylissa massa.](http://blog.openhelix.eu/?p=5004) I could only find that it lives for over 2 months.

Comment: This totally makes sense to me, my driver's license says 50, my wife says 11 going on 9, and when my back is OK I _feel_ 25; when it hurts, more like 80.

Answer (score 0):

If he were the same age since the beginning then the bodyguard episode will make him 14 because they come to party for HIS birthday

Comment: Can you expand? How does the body guard episode make him 14? I've never seen the show so I don't understand the reference.

Comment: @BenPlont I think he based this on the other answer. If he's 13 in the other answer, then celebrating his birthday in the bodyguard episode would make him turn 14.